# Manipulating an expression

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to prove the triangle inequality to prove a function is a metric. Is there any way to show that

$\sqrt {|(x - y) + (y - z)|}$ $\leqslant$ $\sqrt{|x-y|}$ + $\sqrt{|y-z|}$

by some sort of algebra manipulation without considering each individual case of when one variable is negative/positive etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Result 1

If $a,b$ are positive numbers, then $\sqrt{a + b} \leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} $. This follows by noticing that $2 \sqrt{ab} \geq 0 $ trivially. Hence we must have that $2 \sqrt{a +b} + a + b \geq a + b \implies ( \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} )^2 \geq a + b \implies \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} \geq \sqrt{a+b}  $.

### Result 2

By the usual triangle inequality, we have $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b| $. Since $\sqrt{t}$ is an increasing function, then we must have

$$ \sqrt{|a+b|} \leq  \sqrt{|a| + |b|} \leq_{Result \; \; 1} \sqrt{|a|} + \sqrt{|b|}$$

Putting $a = x -y $ and $b = y -z$ gives what you are asking for. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** The basic approach is to square both sides and consider the cases only for the square root. I think it is more direct than the approach I understood your question to imply.

Comment: When I do that, don't I still have to consider all the cases when x < y < z, x < z < y ... etc?

Comment: @rawrPanda It depends what $x,y,z$ are - if you square the expression and you have the triangle equality $|x-z|\le |x-y|+|y-z|$ you are essentially done.